# Using @font-face call to fix font-smoothing issue in Google Chrome screws up font rendering in Firefox. Why?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, fonts, internet-explorer-8

I'm using `@font-face` call to try to solve the font-smoothing issue in Google Chrome (as seen here: http://www.adtrak.co.uk/blog/font-face-chrome-rendering/#fix).

It works perfectly, but then it makes the font look terrible in Firefox, where it used to render properly. In the other hand, IE 8 is rendering horribly both ways.

[image]

This is my CSS:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Montserrat';
src: url('../fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.eot');
src: url('../fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot'),
url('../fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
url('../fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('../fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.svg') format('svg');
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
@font-face {
font-family: 'Montserrat';
src: url('../fonts/montserrat-regular-webfont.svg') format('svg');
}
}
```

How can I manage to fix this issue?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x4X2f

Comment: Is it possible for you to share link of development server or jsfiddle will be helpful to debug code

Comment: Pravin, JSFiddle added.

Comment: well I guess if I am not wrong on fiddle you cant upload assets and share relative path like to images, fonts etc hence even of you check http://jsfiddle.net/x4X2f/show/ this and in firebug if you remove 'Montserrat',sans-serif font there is no change effect which means custom fonts are not linked

Comment: That's what I thought it would happen. Why do you need JSFiddle then? I thought you would just want to have a look at the whole code. How can I help you to get this clear?

Comment: actually from provide image cant figure out till what extent before and after giving you trouble. If there is a snippet with actual code and font url linkup there would be no ambiguity also you may try with online readymade font conversion like 1) http://www.font2web.com/ 2)http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator may help you to get ready made code